# How to extend a common controller by other controllers in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I have extended a common controller by other controllers in Codeigniter. Here is my CI common controller.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Common extends CI_Controller {
        protected $_data = array();
        public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('url','form','html'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','authentication','upload','image_lib','pagination'));

        $this->_data['totalUser'] = 10;
        $this->_data['newUser'] = 2;
        $this->_data['totalChallenge'] = 1;
        $this->_data['totalReport'] = 1;
    }
}
```

This is how I extended it in other CI controllers:-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
include_once('common.php');
class Dashboard extends Common {

        public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['globalData'] = $this->_data;
        $entity = 'dashboard';
        $action = 'view';
        $data['action'] = $action;
        $data['entity'] = $entity;
    $this->authentication->is_loggedin($this->session->userdata('user_name'));
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
    }
}
```

Now, in view page, I can just print the values like `<?php echo $globalData['totalUser'];?>`

**Why am I doing this?**

Suppose, today I need to add 20 more data in all the controllers. Then I will have to change only in the common controller. Since `$data['globalData'] = $this->_data;` will make all 20 data available in every controller, it is easy for coder to write one LOC instead of 20 LOC.

How can I do the above work in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: The concept that you've implemented is totally wrong in Laravel. I suggest you to learn Laravel basics first. Avoid requiring other files in style like this.

Comment: u can keep that in config too.. no need of controller for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you have a base controller located in App\Controller.
You can use it exactly as are you using your CIController, because all the generated controllers (by Artisan) are extending that base project controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create the base controller which extents Laravel Controller in same directory ie(/controllers)

Following sample

```
DashboardController.php
class DashboardController extends \BaseController {

 public function index()
{
    $data['globalData'] = $this->_data;
    $entity = 'dashboard';
    ......


}


BaseController.php (extends laravel Controller)
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     *
     * define your value
     */
    protected $_data = "20";


}
```

please add if anything is missing